# C# simple Lottery Program

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement

This works fine as long as all 3 numbers are different, but if the user inputs 2 or more of the same number and that number matches at least 1 of the random numbers, it comes out with the 3 match outcome ($1000).

What can I do to make sure if the user enters 2 or more of the same number it won't come out as the 3 match?

```
namespace test2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int e1, e2, e3;
            int matches = 0;

            e1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            e2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            e3 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);


            Random LotteryNum = new Random();

            int num1 = LotteryNum.Next(1, 4);
            int num2 = LotteryNum.Next(1, 4);
            int num3 = LotteryNum.Next(1, 4);


            label2.Text = " The winning nummbers are " + num1 + num2 + num3;

            if (e1 == num1 && e2 == num2 && e3 == num3)
            {
                ++matches;
            }
            if (e1 == num1 || e1 == num2 || e1 == num3 && e1 != e2 && e1 != e3)
            {
                ++matches;
            }

            if (e2 == num1 || e2 == num2 || e2 == num3 && e2 != e1 && e2 != e3)
            {
                ++matches;
            }

            if (e3 == num1 || e3 == num2 || e3 == num3 && e3 != e1 && e3 != e2)
            {
                ++matches;
            }

            if (matches == 1)
            {
                label1.Text = "Congratulations! You have won $10!\n";
            }
            else
            {
                if (matches == 2)
                {
                    label1.Text = "Congratulations! You have won $100!\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (matches == 3)
                    {
                        label1.Text = "Congratulations! You have won $1,000!\n";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (matches == 4)
                        {
                            label1.Text = "Congratulations! You have won $10,000!!!\n";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            label1.Text = "I'm sorry, you didn't win.";
                        }
                    }

                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should the matches be position dependent, or does the user need to just match numbers in any order? You should also learn how to write an `else if`, what you have is called arrow code (the if's make an arrow), and you should avoid that.

Comment: This sounds like a *great* opportunity to familiarize yourself with the single most valuable development tool... the debugger.  Run your code in the debugger and step through it, line by line.  You can observe the runtime values and behavior and see where the logic differs from what you expect.

Comment: Yes I already know what it does. if  pick 123 and the random numbers are 313 I will get credit for 3 twice as an example/

Comment: @AMore Simply knowing "what the debugger does" isn't the important thing. The point is, if you step through your code you can find exactly what is being evaluated and how. Then you can find the bad logic when it steps into a condition you don't expect and change the logic accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simplified way to do this:

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> userNums = new List<int>();
    List<int> lotteryNums = new List<int>();

    userNums.Add(Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text));
    userNums.Add(Convert.ToInt32(textbox2.Text));
    userNums.Add(Convert.ToInt32(textbox3.Text));

    Random LotteryNum = new Random();

    lotteryNums.Add(LotteryNum.Next(1, 4));
    lotteryNums.Add(LotteryNum.Next(1, 4));
    lotteryNums.Add(LotteryNum.Next(1, 4));

    lotteryNums.Remove(userNums[0]);
    lotteryNums.Remove(userNums[1]);
    lotteryNums.Remove(userNums[2]);

    if (lotteryNums.Count == 3)
        label1.Text = "You didn't get any matches";
    else if (lotteryNums.Count == 2)
        label1.Text = "You made one match!";
    else if (lotteryNums.Count == 1)
        label1.Text = "You made two matches!";
    else if (lotteryNums.Count == 0)
        label1.Text = "You made three matches, jackpot!";
}
```

It uses two lists, one for the numbers that the user enters, and one for the random numbers. It doesn't matter if they are duplicate, it can only match once. The `lotteryNums.Remove` will remove the **first** instance of the matching number, so even if the user enters the numbers twice, it will only credit them for one match.

Also notice how the `if` statement is formatted, and how much easier it is to read and follow. Try to avoid arrow code, if your `if` statements are more than 2 or 3 levels deep, you may want to rethink how you are doing them.

**Edit**

If you want to count matches, its very simple, change the following:

```
    int matches = 0;
    matches += lotteryNums.Remove(userNums[0]) ? 1 : 0;
    matches += lotteryNums.Remove(userNums[1]) ? 1 : 0;
    matches += lotteryNums.Remove(userNums[2]) ? 1 : 0;
```

The `?:` is called the ternary operator, and its like a short-hand `if` that evaluates to:

```
    if (lotteryNums.Remove(userNums[0]) == true)
        matches += 1;
    else
        matches += 0;
```

Then you can use it in your `if` statement:

```
if (matches == 0)
    label1.Text = "You didn't get any matches";
else if (matches == 1)
    label1.Text = "You made one match!";
else if (matches == 2)
    label1.Text = "You made two matches!";
else if (matches == 3)
    label1.Text = "You made three matches, jackpot!";
```

In the future, when you can use loops, you can simplify it further:

```
foreach(var userNum in userNums)
    matches += lotteryNums.Remove(userNum) ? 1 : 0;
```

Which gives you the flexibility to make a lottery system with different amounts of numbers without having to change any of your code (other than the `if` part that determines winnings, but you can get around that too with another List or Dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend filling two [Lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of integers, one with your lottery numbers and one with the user input. Then you could loop over them and count the matches. This would also allow flexibility if you wanted to allow for position-independent matches by using [`IndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8zse0c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Yeah i seen that but i can not use loops for this projects only if statements

Comment: You should have stated that. Regardless, lists can be compared using if statements too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to store the input integers and random generated integers in two separate lists respectively. Then you want to remove any duplicates before you count the number of matches. So for your example 123 and 313 would become 123 and 31 which would result in two matches. Here is code on how to do it with just if statements:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var e1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            var e2 = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            var e3 = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);

            //Code to display winning numbers here

            var input = new List<int>();
            input.Add(e1);
            if (!input.Contains(e2))
                input.Add(e2);
            if (!input.Contains(e3))
                input.Add(e3);

            var lotteryNum = new Random();

            var randoms = new List<int>();
            randoms.Add(lotteryNum.Next(1,4));
            var rand2 = lotteryNum.Next(1, 4);
            if (!randoms.Contains(rand2))
                randoms.Add(rand2);
            var rand3 = lotteryNum.Next(1, 4);
            if (!randoms.Contains(rand3))
                randoms.Add(rand3);

            //Code to display random numbers here

            //Compare the two lists. Since they both have distinct values respectively no worries of duplicate matches
            var matches = 0;
            if(input.Contains(randoms[0]))
                matches++;
            if (input.Contains(randoms[1]))
                matches++;
            if (input.Contains(randoms[2]))
                matches++;

            //Do logic for displaying matches to user
        }
```

Comment: Although now that I think about it a user shouldn't be allowed to pick the same number twice anyways as they can only get one match for that number anyways and would be wasting a pick.